# Two out of three

Tags: lateral-thinking

**What is hidden below? The answer speaks for itself.**

---

```
                ndetarotraorinenceameyatudowwladuouniteaseiphyorouoo
```

back, time, drink, drink, time, sprint, rest, bird, to, drink, chicken, time, inclusive, back, foot, chicken, inclusive, risk, time, drink

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that there are...

> 52 letters in the string. This is exactly twice the number of letters in the English alphabet. If we can assume that pairs of these letters map to a third letter of the alphabet (hence the 'two out of three' of the title), we can then see that we can break this string into pairs and add the letters of the alphabet (in alphabetical order) to the start of each pair, to produce a set of three-letter words or abbreviations:
>
>  **a**nd**b**et**c**ar**d**ot**e**ra**f**or**g**in**h**en**i**ce**j**am**k**ey**l**at**m**ud**n**ow**o**wl**p**ad**q**uo**r**un**s**it**t**ea**u**se**v**ip**w**hy**x**or**y**ou**z**oo

Now consider the list of 20 words...

> Each of these can be a definition of sorts for (or at least associated with) one (or more) of these three-letter words:
>
>  back = [**l**at](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latissimus_dorsi_muscle)
>  time = **e**ra (or **n**ow)
>  drink = **t**ea (or **g**in)
>  drink = **t**ea (or **g**in)
>  time = **e**ra (or **n**ow)
>  sprint = **r**un
>  rest = **s**it
>  bird = **o**wl (or **h**en)
>  to = **f**or
>  drink = **t**ea (or **g**in)
>  chicken = **h**en
>  time = **e**ra (or **n**ow)
>  inclusive = **a**nd
>  back = **l**at
>  foot = **p**ad
>  chicken = **h**en
>  inclusive = **a**nd
>  risk = **b**et
>  time = **e**ra (or **n**ow)
>  drink = **t**ea (or **g**in)
>
>  If we consistently choose **e**ra as 'time', **o**wl as 'bird', and **t**ea as 'drink' then the initials of the three-letter words we have chosen spell out the phrase **LETTERS OF THE ALPHABET** - this perfectly answers the question 'what is hidden below'!

Comment: Yup, that's it. Nice job!